# Equivalent of query in grpc

Tags: node.js, grpc

Using HTTP, to paginate sequelize data, `req.query.limit` and `req.query.offset` are used. I'm using grpc and `query` doesn't exist. How can I go about this to implement pagination?

`Products.findAll({ limit: 50, offset: 0 }).then((prod) => {
      //
      });`
From above, I don't want to hard code the limit and offset. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Information that would be contained in the query parameters in HTTP requests should generally be sent in the request message(s) in gRPC.